# NodeJS and ExpressJS is there a better way to handle error responses than what I am doing?

Tags: node.js, express

Below I have a very basic post request to create a user via REST API.  Currently if I have a place where an error state happens I am updating the response object and returning the function.  My question is there a better way to do this?  Or am I on the right track?

```
  app.post('/api/user/create', function (request, response)
  {
    // Create variables foreach input.
    var firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password, passwordConfirm, User;
    firstName = validator.trim(request.body.firstName);
    lastName = validator.trim(request.body.lastName);
    emailAddress = validator.trim(request.body.emailAddress);
    password = validator.trim(request.body.password);
    passwordConfirm = validator.trim(request.body.passwordConfirm);

    if(!validator.isEmail(emailAddress))
    {
      response.status(500).send({error: true, message: "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL"});
      return;
    }

    if(password != passwordConfirm)
    {
      response.status(500).send({error: true, message: "ERROR_INPUT_COMPARATOR_PASSWORD_INVALID"});
      return;
    }

    User = db.User;
    User.create({
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      emailAddress: emailAddress,
      password: passwd.crypt(password)
    }).then(function()
    {
      response.status(200).send({error: false, message: "SUCCESS_USER_CREATED"});
    }).error(function(error)
    {
      console.log(error);
      response.status(500).send({error: true, message: error.errors});
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an error middleware and just pass the `Error` instance to `next` callback:

```
if(!validator.isEmail(emailAddress))
{
  var error = new Error();
  error.message = "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL";
  return next(error);
}
```

Register the middleware after all the routes:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    return res.status(500).send({error: true, message: err.message});
});
```

Comment: I read that somewhere and when I tried it it said next was not found, can I just overload the function like this to get access to it?

`app.post('/api/user/create', function (request, response, next)`

Comment: Yes, that's the right way, the third parameter is the `next` callback